# Getting list of connected entities using ndb KeyProperty

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

Using Google App Engine for Python. It seems that when you had connected datastore entities under the old db model you could rather easily get a list of connected entities, but I can't seem to do the same thing with ndb.

I have:

```
class User(ndb.Model):
    username = ndb.StringProperty()

class Collection(ndb.Model):
    owner = ndb.KeyProperty(User)
    name = ndb.StringProperty()
    photos = ndb.StringProperty(repeated=True)
```

So each collection is created with an owner. I thought I would be able to get the User's collections just with:

collections = user.collections

But that results in:

```
    collections = user.collections

AttributeError: 'User' object has no attribute 'collections'
```

From the documentation, it seems that you could do this on db by specifying the collection_name keyword, but I do not see the ndb equivalent.

Comment: FWIW, I found this NDB Cheat Sheet handy (search for "backreference" in there, you'll find Daniel's answer): https://docs.google.com/document/d/1AefylbadN456_Z7BZOpZEXDq8cR8LYu7QgI7bt5V0Iw/mobilebasic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ndb does not create back-references. But it's just as easy to do the query forwards:

```
 Collection.query(Collection.user==user.key)
```